# Format a number to string, fill 0 when it's not enough two characters

Tags: kotlin

I want to format the number to `String` and fill `0` when it's not enough two characters

```
fun formatDuration(val duration):String {
    val minutes = duration.toInt() / 60
    return  "$minutes"
}
```

For example, if `minutes` is 6， it should displayed `06` rather than `6`.

Comment: 06 is not a valid literal in Int type. You can add "0" as string in there via if expression or padstart.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can `padStart` the `toString()` result of `minutes`.

I tried your code in the Kotlin Playground and it wasn't compilable / runnable. For the following example, I had to change parts of your `fun`:

```
fun main() {
    println(formatDuration(364.34))
}

fun formatDuration(duration: Double): String {
    val minutes = duration.toInt() / 60
    // fill the result to be of 2 characters, use 0 as padding char
    return minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')
}
```

Executing this results in the output `06`.

Alternatively, you can simply use `String.format()` from Java, just

```kotlin
return "%02d".format(minutes)
```

instead of `return minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')`, the result stays the same.

Answer (score 8):

You can achive this with [`padStart`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-start.html)

Example:

```
val padWithSpace = "125".padStart(5)
println("'$padWithSpace'") // '  125'

val padWithChar = "a".padStart(5, '.')
println("'$padWithChar'") // '....a'

// string is returned as is, when its length is greater than the specified
val noPadding = "abcde".padStart(3)
println("'$noPadding'") // 'abcde'
```